Why is $\text{LMod}_A$ a category?
Let $\newcommand{\LM}{\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}}\DeclareMathOperator{\LMod}{LMod}\DeclareMathOperator{\Alg}{Alg}\DeclareMathOperator{\Assoc}{\mathcal{A}ssoc^{\otimes}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Assocone}{\textbf{Assoc}} \LM$ be the "left modules operad" as defined in HA, Def. 4.2.1.7. One can then define the category of left modules over a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\newcommand{\Ccat}{\mathcal{C}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Fin}{\mathcal{F}in}\Ccat^{\otimes} \to N(\Fin_\ast)$ simply as
$$
\LMod(\Ccat) := \Alg_{\LM}(\Ccat^{\otimes}).
$$
A structural feature of $\LM$ is that it admits a functor $a: \Assoc \to \LM$ (which is in particular an inner fibration, since it's a map obtained by applying the nerve), which yields a forgetful functor
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\fgt}{fgt}\fgt: \LMod(\Ccat) \to \Alg(\Ccat);
$$
one can then define the category of left modules over $A \in \Alg(\Ccat)$ simply via the following pullback square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 \LMod_A(\Ccat) @>>> \LMod(\Ccat)\\
@VVV @VV{\fgt}V \\
\ast @>>> \Alg(\Ccat)
\end{CD}
$$
Question. Why is $\LMod_A(\Ccat) \to \ast$ an inner fibration, i.e. $\LMod_A(\Ccat)$ is an $\infty$-category?
Lurie claims that $\fgt$ is a categorical fibration in HA Def. 4.2.1.13 without giving any explanation, but why is this true? I see that $\text{Fun}(K,-)$ preserves inner fibrations for any simplicial set $K$, but here we are considering (a variation of) $\text{Fun}(-,K)$, so I don't quite understand what's going on. I'm sorry if the question is a bit trivial.

What does this question have to do with algebraic topology?

I don't have anything useful to say and my comment here doesn't answer the question but I would take the pullback inside $\mathsf{Cat}_{\infty}$, that's a more model-invariant viewpoint and removes all the headache with inner fibrations and so on. Of course, your question would then translate to saying that this can be modelled by a pullback in $\mathsf{sSet}$.

@MartinBrandenburg $\infty$-categories are a concept of homotopical nature, and in the example above I usually want to consider $\mathcal{C} = \text{Sp}$. But yes, this question doesn't really make use of these things, so I'll remove these tags.

I'm not familiar with operads and all that stuff, but as far as I can tell, the fibration $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes}\rightarrow\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes}$ is a pullback (in the $\infty$-categorical sense) of the fibration $\mathcal{O}^{\otimes}\rightarrow\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}$ (Def. 4.2.1.12) and the functor $\mathrm{Alg}{/\mathcal{LM}}(\mathcal{O})\rightarrow\mathrm{Alg}{\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes}}(\mathcal{C})$ is obtained by taking the pullback on categories of sections and restricting to certain full subcategories.

The latter I don't understand, but the former is a categorical fibration and this is a (not too difficult) fact about $\infty$-categories you can formulate without any reference to operads. That is, in $\infty$-categories, if $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is a pullback of a fibration of $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}$ along a monomorphism (the fibrancy assumption guarantees this is also an $\infty$-categorical pullback), then the pullback map $\mathrm{Fun}{\mathcal{E}}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow\mathrm{Fun}{\mathcal{D}}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{C})$ is a categorical fibration.

@Thorgott right, I guess that if you have a monomorphism $A \hookrightarrow B$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-category, then $\text{Fun}(B, \mathcal{C}) \to \text{Fun}(A, \mathcal{C})$ is still an inner fibration. Then for operads in general, you have that $\text{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{C})  \subset \text{Fun}(B, \mathcal{C})$ as a full subcategory, so the induced map on the algebra categories is again an inner fibration. This seems reasonable; if you want to make your comment into an answer, I can then approve it.

@Frusciante Your first claim is true, but a categorical fibration is more than an inner fibration, so this is slightly more complicated than that. However, on second thought, I'm confused by Lurie's statement again. My remark only really helps in case that the pullback in question is strict, but if we can freely change $\mathcal{C}$ up to equivalence, how does our claim even make sense? Being a categorical fibration is not a property invariant under equivalence. There must be something I'm missing due to my lack of familiarity...

@Thorgott for the first part, you are right; but actually, Lurie later shows (4.2.3.2) that $\text{fgt}$ is Cartesian, so in particular also an isofibration, so a categorical fibration (this is not super satisfactory but at least I can make sense of the claim).
For the second part, in Lurie's definition $\text{LMod}(\mathcal{C})$ really depends on the whole coCartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes}$, so you can somehow change $\mathcal{C}$ up to equivalence, but the whole $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes}$ is part of the data in the definition still. Or am I missing your point?

I am a bit confused about what is left to show: by Lurie's definition, $\mathcal{C}^\otimes\to\mathbb{A}\mathrm{ssoc}^\otimes$ is a strict pullback of $\mathcal{O}^\otimes\to\mathcal{LM}^\otimes$, and we know then that $\mathrm{Alg}{/\mathcal{LM}^\otimes}(\mathcal{O}^\otimes)\to\mathrm{Alg}{/\mathbb{A}\mathrm{ssoc}^\otimes}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)$ is the restriction of a categorical fibration to full subcategories that are closed under equivalences. But any such restriction is necessarily again a categorical fibration, so we are done, no?

@DaniëlApol on my part I'm satisfied by Thorgott's argument, and was waiting for an official answer so to accept it. We weren't also quite sure why algebras are closed under equivalences though, but this point can be somehow bypassed I guess.

First of all, as I mentioned in the comments, there is the following general observation:
Lemma: If
\begin{CD}
X^{\prime} @>>> X\\
@VVV @V{p}VV\\
S^{\prime} @>{f}>> S
\end{CD}
is a pullback diagram of simplicial sets, in which the right (hence left) vertical map is a categorical fibration and the bottom (hence top) horizontal map is a cofibration (i.e. monomorphism), then the map of $\infty$-categories $f^{\ast}\colon\mathrm{Map}_S(S,X)\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}_{S^{\prime}}(S^{\prime},X^{\prime})$ induced by pullback along $f$ is a categorical fibration.
Proof: The universal property of the pullback induces a canonical isomorphism $\mathrm{Map}_{S^{\prime}}(S^{\prime},X^{\prime})=\mathrm{Map}_{S^{\prime}}(S^{\prime},X)$, and $f^{\ast}$ is really given by pre-composition with $f$ under this identification. Now, a lifting problem of $A\rightarrow B$ against the $f^{\ast}$ un-curries to a lifting problem of $A\times S\sqcup_{A\times S^{\prime}}B\times S^{\prime}\rightarrow B\times S$ against $p\colon X\rightarrow S$. The class of categorical fibrations is closed under pushout-product with monomorphisms (which $f$ is by assumption), so (since $p$ is a categorical fibration by assumption) $f^{\ast}$ is a categorical fibration.
In the present context, Def. 4.2.1.12 postulates that we have a strict pullback diagram
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}^{\otimes} @>>> \mathcal{O}^{\otimes}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes} @>>> \mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}
\end{CD}
and this satisfies the Lemma's hypotheses, so we obtain a categorical fibration $\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}}(\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes},\mathcal{O}^{\otimes})\rightarrow\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes}}(\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes},\mathcal{C}^{\otimes})$. The map $\mathrm{Alg}_{/\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}}(\mathcal{O}^{\otimes})\to\mathrm{Alg}_{/\mathrm{Assoc}^{\otimes}}(\mathcal{C}^{\otimes})$ is obtained by restricting this map to full subcategories. Now, a categorical fibration between $\infty$-categories is the same thing as an isofibration, and it is clear that a restriction to full subcategories closed under equivalences of an isofibration is again an isofibration.
Thus, the last thing to observe is that $\mathrm{Alg}_{/\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}}(\mathcal{O}^{\otimes})$ is closed under equivalence. An equivalence here is a natural equivalence of functors $\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}^{\otimes}$ that is fiberwise over $\mathcal{LM}^{\otimes}$. It is true, more generally, that being a map of $\infty$-operads is invariant under natural equivalence of functors $\mathcal{O}^{\otimes}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}$ over $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$ (for any two $\infty$-operads $\mathcal{O}^{\otimes},\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}\rightarrow\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$). To be a map of $\infty$-operads means (1) being a map over $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$ (this is clearly preserved by a fiberwise homotopy over $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$) and (2) preserving inert morphisms, but inert morphisms are by defintion the cocartesian lifts of inert morphisms of $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$ and so it remains to observe that the image morphism in $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_{\ast})$ does not change since the equivalence is fiberwise and that cocartesian edges are closed under equivalence.
